# Confused about use of Class over php functions()

Tags: php, function, class, oop, methods

So far, I have only been using functions() in php and I am fairly confortable with it. The past few days I am learning about classes since I have no idea about that. After reading a lot of info in SO, php manual and other tutorials, I kinda understand about the overview of classes, properties and methods. But still, I feel confused on how I am going to use them.

As an example, lets say these are the functions I have atm:

```
function validate_text($xyz)   
{
    $xyz = trim($xyz);
    $xyz = htmlspecialchars($xyz); 
    return $xyz;
}

function validate_checkbox($values,$db)
{
    $stmt = $db->query("SELECT values FROM checkbox_info_table");   
    foreach ($stmt as $row)
    {
        $result_values[] = $row['value'];
    }   
    $filteredData = array_intersect($checkboxValues, $result_values);
    return $filteredData;

}

function fetch_checkbox($type,$db)
{
    $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM checkbox_info_table WHERE type=$type");   
    foreach ($stmt as $row)
    {
        $row_id[] = $row['id'];
        $row_type[] = $row['type'];
        $row_values[] = $row['value'];
        $row_description[] = $row['description'];
    }   
    return array($row_id, $row_type, $row_values, $row_description);

}


etc...etc..
```

I then call these functions like these:

```
$name = validate_text($_POST["name"]);
$nickname = validate_text($_POST["nickname"]);

$carscheckbox = validate_checkbox($_POST['cars'], $db);
$bikescheckbox = validate_checkbox($_POST['bikes'], $db);
$planecheckbox = validate_checkbox($_POST['planes'], $db);    

$fetch_checkbox = fetch_checkbox($type, $db); //then storing the fetched array values to variables    

etc..etc..
```

**My questions are:**

**1)** When do I decide where to use classes instead of functions and when not to use classes?

**2)** What will be the benefits if I used classes instead for functions in the above example? For instance, the usage of functions in the above example is quite easy by itself. How will I benefit if I replaced them to classes?

**3)** Is it better for me to always prefer using classes instead of functions or does each has its pros and cons?

**4)** Is there a right way to approach classes? How do people decide usually?

**5)** Is there any difference performance wise between functions and classes?

If you can extend further on this and not just based on this example alone will also be helpful with my learning curve.

Comment: I think you should learn more about advantages/disadvantages of OOP. http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/post/178-Why-is-it-better-to-develop-in-PHP-with-classes-OOP.html

Comment: Your question is not really a good fit for SO for a number of reasons. 1). It is more than one question. 2). The answers to most of them are a matter of opinion. 3). SO is not a good medium for teaching this kind of thing, you will be better off with a good book on the basics of OOP (don't restrict yourself to PHP books here, in fact, best to avoid them). If you have 'specific programming questions' on code you are writing as a result of your studies, then this is definitely the place to ask. Good luck.

Comment: AleVale94 - Thank you for that blog link. It certainly helps. @vascowhite - I will take your advise on getting a book on OOP. Although there are lots of info on the internet, reading bits and pieces here and there only partially make sense and it leaves me with a lot of doubts and questions. Hopefully a complete beginners book might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of a class in a page named **confirm.php in class folder**:

```
class Category {

function get_category($link) {
  //rest of code
  } 
}
```

This is useful when you want to use methods in another .php files.

For example, at the top of a php file:

```
include 'class/confirm.php';
$category = new Category();
```

Usage:

```
$type = $category->get_category(link);
```

This way you ensure your class is clean, simpler and easier to maintain. Instead of having all the code and functions in one place (harder to read).

Also, classes often mean something or can be used as a utility for something else, like using a specific function from a class when needed only. You can think of it as building relations and dependability between tasks.

Comment: anytime, if you think it's an answer, mark it :) happy learning